# Angular Routing , browser URL not updating as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, route-provider

I have an angular app and i am using partial views in the app and routing using $routeProvider , the app is hosted in a server ,everything works great.

The URL to launch the app is something like http://servername/?instanceId=862gh2g2323238

note that the instance ID is required to launch the app , the homepage of the app consists of a list of recipes

Here is sample code how the routes are set

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "views/view_index.html",
        controller : "mainCtrl"

    })
    .when("/recipe/:index", {
        templateUrl : "views/view_recipe.html",
        controller : "recipeCtrl"   

    });
```

In my view_index.html i have

```
<a ng-href= "#recipe/{{index}}" >...
```

to call the respective view for the recipe

Issue it in the browser when i click any recipe to get to the details page the browser url changes to

URL://servername/?instanceId=862gh2g2323238#/recipe/0

i am expecting it to be something like

http://servername/#/recipe/0?instanceId=862gh2g2323238

please let me know , what i may be missing ??

Answer (score 0):

`"#recipe/{{index}}"` is a **relative** link, so this will be added to your current url. If you want to point to an **absolute** url, you need to start with `/`, so in your case try:

```
<a ng-href="/#/recipe/{{index}}">...</a>
```

Comment: Now the View wont load properly do i need to change anything in my app.config code mentioned above .